# (gcloud.app.deploy) HTTPError 403: <account> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

When I try to follow the example here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart,

```
gcloud app deploy
```

gives me the below error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) HTTPError 403: *account1* does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
```

However, the account: account1 is the owner of the particular project. So why an ower does not have the storage.objects.get access here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved by adding **Storage Object Admin** role to the account.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting a bit and re-run "gcloud app deploy". I had the same problem with a different example app. [Build and deploy a C# .NET Core service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/c-sharp) I believe it's a timing issue during the build process.